# paypal create app, nothing select account and all business account display error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Conside the following...

[image]

My paypal account has nothing selected inside the sandbox account. 
I can go to the sandbox account list and view any business account, however an error `We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. Please delete it and try again.` is displayed

I delete and create account again, but problem is not resolved.
How would one go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Right! I posted the same question yesterday but got no replies. This issue has been driving me mad x.x

Now there is a solution!

SOLUTION:

```
<option>YOURACCOUNT</option>
```

1. In the above HTML snippet replace YOURACCOUNT with the auto generated 
   sandbox business account email (the one that has facilitator in its name).
2. Then copy it to clipboard (CTRL-C)
3. From Firefox Right Click and 'Inspect Element' on the empty dropdown selectbox.
4. Right Click the highlighted  node in the Inspector.
5. Select 'Paste'
6. Select 'As First Child'

Now you can DO IT yay \0/ \0/ \0/ :D